# Unknown column 'rates_test' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the below mysqli command which gives the error message

> Unknown column 'rates_test' in 'where clause'

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName =" . $assigntable);
```

`$id` is a number returned by another query

`$assigntable` is a string passed to the function that the above query is in but basically

```
$assigntable = array_search('Assign', $_POST);
```

And so will have the value `rates_test`

I can not work out what is wrong with the syntax of the query and what is even odder if I change it to

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName ='$assigntable'");
```

Which is one of the things I tried, I get

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

```
$string = "UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName =".$assigntable;
```

Outputs

> UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=Array WHERE TableName =rates_test

```
$string = "UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName ='" . $assigntable . "'";
```

Outputs

> UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=Array WHERE TableName ='rates_test'

Comment: Put the query into a string.  Then print out the string after the variable substitution.  99% of the time, the problem is obvious when you debug it correctly.

Comment: Just because you've changed `mysql_` to `mysqli_` it doesn't fix security. You're still injecting variables into your SQL meaning you're very vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Show us how $id is formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very obvious from your output

> UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=Array WHERE TableName ='rates_test'

that `$id` is **not** *a number returned by another query*.

So there's your problem. Use `var_dump($id)` or `print_r($id)` to figure out where the real number is, and then refer to it (eg. `$id["number"]`).

Comment: Yup I see now that Id was not what I thought and fixed it thank you

Comment: @ZacPowell I doubt you *really* fixed that

Comment: @YourCommonSense explain?

Answer (score 0):

## Your case is a clear eample why you ought to use prepared statements

instead of stuffing your values directly into query.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=? WHERE TableName=?"); 
$stmt->bindParam("ss",$id, $assigntable);
$stmt->execute();
```

it have to be.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using something to prevent SQL injection. Your second try will work, but it appears that the value of $id is not what you think it is!

Try echoing out the query thus:

```
echo "UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName ='$assigntable'"
```

and see what you get.

Comment: Yup looks like $id is infact 'Array' not a number, and yes I know I need to prevent sql injection but wanted to get this working first

Comment: So correct what is assigning a value to $id and you will have it working. I'd suggest moving to prepared statements. It will make your life easier and prevent injection.

Answer (score -2):

If you are sure you have `rates_test` in `$assigntable` variable, then change:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName =" . $assigntable);
```

To:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Custom_Rates SET UserID=$id WHERE TableName ='" . $assigntable . "'");
```